# Im making a game on but i cant get my lives to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im making an online game (by that I mean a local game but is coded on the internet) where an image is constantly going to your mouse pointer and you have to try and avoid it. If the image touches your mouse cursor than you lose a life but the live counter is not working properly even though I searched this on many websites and they all told me the same thing. Im working on it right now.  Im quite new to this so I don't understand much but please help me fix this. Thank you! This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>starving teacher</title>
<style>
div {
  width: 1800px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="live"></p>
<div onmousemove="moveImg(event)">
<img onmouseover="livelost(event)" src='face.jpg' id='face' />
</div>
<script>
var lives = 10
</script>

<script>
<script>
document.getElementById("live").innerHTML = var lives
</script>

<script>
function wait(ms)
{
    var d = new Date();
    var d2 = null;
    do { d2 = new Date(); }
    while(d2-d < ms);
}
</script>

<script>
function moveImg(event) {
wait(100);
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var face = document.getElementById("face");
    face.style.left = x+'px';
    face.style.top = y+'px';
}
</script>

<script>
function livelost(event) {
    var lives = var lives - 1
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors in your code. Try using a code editor and it will highlight your mistakes. [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is a quite popular choice.

Comment: @Mellet I was using notepad++ before but now i have vs code and its much better, thanks

Comment: Now for your question we need some clarifications, feel free to update your question with the following:
When is the counter supposed to go down?
What is the game supposed to be?

Comment: @Mellet Ok I updated it.

Comment: now that you have vs code.. check out extensions like javascript ES6, TabNine, and Prettier..youtube them.. they will help you by offering autocomplete code and alerting/fixing issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible starting point.
I would recommend reading up on how to make browser games.
Here are some resources:
[quick-tip-game-loop-in-javascript](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-game-loop-in-javascript/)
[Pong1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhRJb58tOlA)
[Pong2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nl0KXCa5pJk)

```
<p id="live">10</p>

<div id="game">
  <img src="face.jpg" id="face" />
</div>

<script>
  const face = document.getElementById("face");
  const live = document.getElementById("live");
  let lives = 10;

  document.getElementById("live").innerHTML = lives;

  function moveFace() {
    // Add logic to move face how you want
  }

  // Function to reduce life
  function lostLife() {
    lives = lives - 1;
    live.innerHTML = lives;
  }

  function draw() {
    // Add logic to move face closer to mouse
    // Check if face and mouse are at same position, if so reduce life, maybe reset face position
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

  function gameLoop() {
    draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ok ill try to work on this and i will look at the guides you linked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Only Declare your variables Once. not every time you use it

something like...

```
let lives = 10

document.getElementById("live").innerHTML = lives

function wait(ms)
{
    var d = new Date();
    var d2 = null;
    do { d2 = new Date(); }
    while(d2-d < ms);
}

function moveImg(event) {
wait(100);
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var face = document.getElementById("face");
    face.style.left = x+'px';
    face.style.top = y+'px';
}

function livelost() {
if(lives === 0) {
alert('GAME OVER')
} else if ( lives > 0) {
    lives = lives -1
    document.getElementById("live").innerHTML = lives
    }
  }
```

so only remaining lives show...

```
<p>Lives Left: <span id="live"></span></p>
```

Comment: and you only typically need only one <script> tag with all the js